# Image size getting bigger after selecting from gallery?

Tags: android

I have a Image in my local gallery that has a size of 1.61 mb but when I select the image using the code below and log the size it became 6mb! How is it possible that the image size get's bigger or my computation or way of getting the byte is wrong.

selecting image using this.

```
 Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

getting bitmap bytes using this.

```
bytes = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();

public static String humanReadableByteCount(long bytes, boolean si) {
int unit = si ? 1000 : 1024;
if (bytes < unit) return bytes + " B";
int exp = (int) (Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(unit));
String pre = (si ? "kMGTPE" : "KMGTPE").charAt(exp-1) + (si ? "" : "i");
return String.format("%.1f %sB", bytes / Math.pow(unit, exp), pre);
}
```

Comment: The file you see in the gallery is compressed. Once you open it and calculate the size the image is decompressed.

Comment: in that case look's there is no problem in my code. thanks!